# What does "Invalid protocol" mean"

Tags: 11.10, dolphin

I was trying to do a search using Dolphin file manager and, when I start typing the file name in the search box, I get the message "Invalid protocol" after the first 4 characters and I cannot do the search.  I want to do the search on my hard drive.  What does the message mean? I have a screen shot of the error but I can't figure out how to post it here.

Answer (score 4):

Install the metapackage `kde-baseapps`.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you have uninstalled konqueror and its libraries, try installing **kfind** package from the terminal *(Konsole)*:

```
sudo apt-get install kfind
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to install the missing package 'baloo' which performs the search in Dolphin.

Do the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install baloo
```

That worked on KXStudio 14.04, and might help for other distros based on Ubuntu 14.04.